# Realm.objects() returns empty objects

Tags: ios, swift, realm

My class has all properties as dynamic but still when retrieving them from realm i get a collection of empty objects, and check the realm db with the realm browser and the data is there, this is my class:

```
class ProjectEntity: Object {

    /**
    Property: All properties of the ProjectEntity 
    **/
    dynamic var ProjectId = 0
    dynamic var ProjectTitle = ""
    dynamic var ProjectSubtitle = ""
    dynamic var ProjectType = ""
    dynamic var ProjectClass = ""
    dynamic var ProjectCoordinates = ""
    dynamic var ProjectGraphType = ""
    dynamic var ProjectModifiedOn = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 0)
    dynamic var ProjectCity = ""
    dynamic var ProjectCounty = ""
    dynamic var ProjectZip = ""

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "ProjectId"
    }

    func getShape() -> MapShape{
        let adapter = ProjectsJSONAdapter()
        let shape: MapShape = adapter.parseShape(id: self.ProjectId, type: self.ProjectGraphType, jsonStr: self.ProjectCoordinates)
        return shape
    }
}
```

here is how i'm reading the data:

```
    let projectsList = realm.objects(ProjectEntity)
    for project in projectsList {
        projects.append(project)//The properties in project have all their default/empty values
    }
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you retrieving the persisted `ProjectEntity` objects? The following code snippet should do the trick:

```
let entities = Realm().objects(ProjectEntity)
```

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what i'm doing but once i loop through the entity collection each ProjectEntity is empty: here it the code:         let projectsList = realm.objects(ProjectEntity)
        for project in projectsList {
            projects.append(project) //this project has all its properties with their default/empty values
        }

Comment: i read in other posts that adding "dynamic" to the props should fixt it, but it did not in my case, anything else i could be missing?

Comment: Could you be more specific on what's unexpected about the behavior you're seeing?

Comment: When i loop through the "for project in projectsList" it loops through it 582 times, but each project has all its properties empty. I opened the realm file with the realm browser and i see all 582 records with data; let me know if this clarifies it, and thanks again

Comment: Are you viewing the objects in the debugger? If so, that's expected. Does the object still appear "empty" when calling `println`?

Comment: exactly, the issue was i was only looking at the debuger, which always show them empty but if i do an println is show the data, so there was no issue really; thanks a lot for the help

Comment: I saw the same problem too, in the debugger, the realm object is empty, led to a lot of misunderstanding, hope the realm team can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

first your class need to inherit RLMObject :

```
class ProjectEntity: RLMObject {
    ...
}
```

and after if you want all the ProjectEntity objects try this :

```
let allProjectEntityObjects: RLMResults = ProjectEntity.allObjects()
```

if you need some extra help you can follow this tutorial from Realm :

[Building a To-Do App with Realm](https://realm.io/news/tutorial-building-a-todo-app-with-realm/)

Comment: Thanks but did not work, i get an error "ProjectEntity.Type does not have a member named 'allObjects'", i'm using realm 0.95.0 for swift if that helps