# Realm.objects(Type) return empty objects

Tags: swift, realm

I'm a new in Xcode development and I need some help with Realm database
.. these are my tables

```
class Parent: Object {
    var id :Int = 0
    var name: String = ""
}

class Surah: Parent {
    dynamic var ayatNum = 0

    private var fav : Bool {
        set { self.fav = newValue }
        get { return self.fav }
    }

    init(id: Int , ayat: Int , name: String) {
        super.init()
        super.id = id
        self.ayatNum = ayat
        super.name = name
    }

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }

    required init(realm: RLMRealm, schema: RLMObjectSchema) {
        super.init()
    }

    required init(value: AnyObject, schema: RLMSchema) {
        super.init()
    }

    required init() {
        super.init()
    }
}

class Reader: Parent{
    private var fav: Bool {
        set { self.fav = newValue }
        get { return self.fav }
    }

    init(id: Int , name: String) {
        super.init()
        self.id = id
        self.name = name

    }

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }

    required init(realm: RLMRealm, schema: RLMObjectSchema) {
        super.init()
    }

    required init(value: AnyObject, schema: RLMSchema) {
        super.init()
    }

    required init() {
        super.init()
    }
}
```

and when I call these lines and store the results in an array and print it

```
realm = try!Realm()
readers = Array(realm.objects(Reader.self))
print(readers)
```

and I try this one also

```
readers = Array(try!Realm().objects(Reader.self))
print(readers)
```

it prints an empty objects

```
Reader {
    id = 0;
    name = ;
}, Reader {
    id = 0;
    name = ;
}, Reader {
    id = 0;
    name = ;
}
```

I search about this problem in stackoverflow and find that solution which did not solve my problem

[Realm.objects() returns empty objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32230802/realm-objects-returns-empty-objects)

can any one help me !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your `Parent` class properties aren't declared as `dynamic`. Most of the property in the Realm must be declared as `dynamic` (Exception is the List and LinkingObjects). Realm loaded all values lazily for performance. All property access is replaced specialized accessor at runtime. So you should declare the properties as `dynamic`. Like the following:

```
class Parent :Object{
    dynamic var id: Int=0
    dynamic var name: String=""
}
```

See https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#cheatsheet

Also, `Surah` class and `Reader` class will be much more simpler using `convenience` initializer. If so, You don't need to override `init(realm: RLMRealm, schema: RLMObjectSchema)`, `init(value: AnyObject, schema: RLMSchema)` and `init()`.

```
class Surah :Parent {
    dynamic var ayatNum = 0

    private var fav : Bool {
        set { self.fav = newValue }
        get { return self.fav }
    }

    convenience init(id: Int , ayat:Int , name:String) {
        self.init()
        self.id = id
        self.ayatNum = ayat
        self.name = name

    }
}

class Reader : Parent {
    private var fav : Bool {
        set { self.fav = newValue }
        get { return self.fav }
    }

    convenience init(id: Int , name:String) {
        self.init()
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }

}
```

Comment: thaaanks alot super

Comment: oh, you saved me.

Answer (score -1):

Try this to add get object from realm

```
let realm = try! Realm()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // retrieve all objects from realm
    let readers = realm.objects(Reader)
    print(readers)
}
```

Comment: the data is already in the database , I can see the data in Realm browser but when I try to get it and print it, it prints empty properties !!

Comment: I updated my answer, i always use that way without fail